# Unable to have a Vim-like window-size-increase in Screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I see

[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/screen-bigger.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/screen-bigger.png)

where I have two windows open in Screen's split.

I would like to increase the zise of the window at the bottom by

```
Ctrl-A [number] +
```

similarly as you can do in Vim.

I did not find a solution by Google.

**How can you increase the size of the window in Screen?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`man screen`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=screen&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+5.0+lenny&format=html&locale=en), which is really what you need to read if you want to do any `screen` hacking:

```
resize

Resize the current region. The space will be removed from or  added  to
the  region below or if there's not enough space from the region above.

       resize +N   increase current region height by N

       resize -N   decrease current region height by N

       resize  N   set current region height to N

       resize  =   make all windows equally high

       resize  max maximize current region height

       resize  min minimize current region height
```

`screen` isn't `vim` - trying to copy the exact same keybindings will give you some
funky behaviour.  In this case, it'd just be a real PITA.

```
 bind -c resize24 + resize +24
 bind -c resize24 - resize -24
 bind -c resize24 ^M resize 24
 bind -c resize2 4 command -c resize24
 bind 2 command -c resize2
```

You'd have to do that for every number that you wanted to use.  So don't do that.  Learn to use `^A:resize`, instead.

Comment: @rampion: Thank you for your answer and for the tip about the manual!